# Can we use reflection to get a static member of a class without invoking that method on an object instance?

Tags: java, class, reflection

Can we use reflection to get a static member of a class without invoking that method on an object instance?

In other words:

```
 public class MuchoStatic {

    private static staticMember;

    getStaticMember(){

    return this.staticMember;

    }
    } //end class
```

then there's more code:

```
Method m = null;

try{

  m = MuchoStatic.class.getMethod("getStaticMember",null);

} catch (Exception e) {

}

Object o = null;
try{

 o = m.invoke(MuchoStatic.class,null);

} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

I am getting an illegal argument exception, I assume it's because I am passing a Class object into the invoke method. It turns out the Object o is actually instatiated, but the exception is still thrown.

Shouldn't we be able to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we use

```
setAccessible(true);
```

with the field, it is not even needed to have the method in the equation

```
Field f = MuchoStatic.class.getField("staticMember");
Object theStatic = f.get(null);
```

Of course, this is **not** recommended... Tinkering with private is not a nice thing. Don't tinker *others privates*!

[Ideone fiddle](http://ideone.com/HB5WWC)

Comment: Some every five years someone finds the ultimate answer useful.

Answer (score 6):

> Can we use reflection to get a static member of a class without invoking that method on an object instance?

Of course, as it is static.

```
Object o = null;
try {
    Method m = MuchoStatic.class.getMethod("getStaticMember");
    m.setAccessible(true);
    o = m.invoke(null);

} catch (Exception e) {
    // don't ignore the exception as it may be trying to tell you something
    throw new AssertionError(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but I am getting a NPE from inside the invoke method. Is there a way to get to the field directly, without having to invoke the getter on it?

Comment: @AlexMills Yes, you should have make the method static as it doesn't need an instance.

Answer (score 2):

You [don't need an instance to invoke the static method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) and since it doesn't take any arguments, simply

```
o = m.invoke(null);
```

If your classes are not in the same package, you will have problems however, because the method is declared as package private. You might need to call

```
m.setAccessible(true);
```

before `invoke()`.